# Why does the writer use 'beneath' here rather than 'on'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

In this [blog](https://www.pushplinen.com/blog/top-sheet-vs-flat-sheet-vs-fitted-sheet/#:%7E:text=A%20top%20sheet%20is%20literally%20a%20flat%20sheet%20which%20bed%20users%20lie%20beneath) about bed linens, there is such a sentence:

> A top sheet is literally a flat sheet which bed users lie **beneath**.

Isn't a sheet something a person lies **on**? Why does the writer use 'beneath' rather than 'on'?

Comment: ? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322665/is-a-top-sheet-on-a-blanket-or-underneath-a-blanket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the *top sheet* is on top. The sleeper lies on the bottom sheet, and the top sheet lies on them.

When you say the sleeper lies beneath the top sheet, that means the top sheet lies on top of them.

[Wikipedia *bed sheet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_sheet)

"A **bottom sheet** is laid above the mattress, and may be either a flat sheet or a fitted sheet (a sheet which has been sewn with elastic or a drawstring along the hem of the top, sides and bottom of the sheet to prevent it from slipping off of the mattress). A **top sheet**, in the many countries where they are used, is a flat sheet, which is placed above a bottom sheet and below other bedding."

The sleeper goes in between them.

Comment: I thought a sheet is something you lay on.

Comment: See the reference added to the answer.

Comment: @Michael - the correct verb is 'lie'.

Comment: In the pre-duvet days one slept [between the sheets](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/between+the+sheets). That's one underneath the person and one above the person. They are to keep the other bedding clean (they can be easily changed and washed) and to make the bed feel comfortable.