# Is a top sheet on a blanket or underneath a blanket?

Tags: meaning

In this [blog](https://www.pushplinen.com/blog/top-sheet-vs-flat-sheet-vs-fitted-sheet/#:%7E:text=Flat/top%20sheets%20are,be%20washed%20as%20frequently.), there is an explanation of top/flat sheets as shown below.

> Flat/top sheets are generally placed on top of the fitted sheets and tucked in on the bottom and sides, **underneath** the comforter or blanket. Flat sheets additionally make bed linens inviting. They at the same time **safeguard the blanket** from becoming dirty, so it does not need to be washed as frequently.

It says that a top sheet is **underneath** a blanket. If a top sheet is to **safeguard the blanket** from becoming dirty, why isn't it **on** the blanket?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322663/why-does-the-writer-use-beneath-here-rather-than-on ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the writer use 'beneath' here rather than 'on'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322663/why-does-the-writer-use-beneath-here-rather-than-on)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about learning English (OP seems to understand the meaning perfectly); it's more about housekeeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layers from top to bottom:

- blanket
- top sheet
- sleeping person
- bottom sheet
- mattress

The top sheet protects the blanket from the person sleeping in the bed. Their sweat, the oils from their skin, and so forth will go onto the top sheet, and not onto the blanket above. To protect the blanket on top, the top sheet must go between the blanket and the sleeping person, which means the top sheet is *on* the sleeper, and the sleeper is *underneath* the top sheet.

Comment: That makes things so clear.

Answer (score 1):

The top sheet is a barrier between the blanket and the person. People often go to bed without bathing, and they frequently sweat while sleeping. The sheet prevents all of that from spoiling the blanket.

Comment: So you mean that the writer used the wrong preposition?

Comment: No, I'm saying it's perfectly correct. The top sheet is over the person and under the blanket.